# Field doesn't have a default value || foreign keys

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

I am trying to use a foreign key in my projectController, in order to get the name of the domain it belongs to. But, when I try to run this command : php artisan db:seed --class=ProjectTableSeeder. I got this error :
'domain_id' doesn't have a default value.

Any Idea please, where it comes from ?

This my migration create_project_table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('code');         
        $table->integer('domain_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('domain_id')->references('id')->on('domains');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Project_Controller :

```
public function create()
{
    //

    $arrondissements = Arrondissement::pluck('arrondissement', 'id');
    return view('pros.create', compact('arrondissements'));
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code from the `ProjectTableSeeder` class?

Comment: It seems you have run migration before you have added `nullable()` constraint... Either you add constraint with new migration, or re-create table... with edited migration... Note: I have reproduced your problem with this scenario.

Comment: @ArtenesNogueira I checked ProjectTableSeeder, I forgot to add domain_id. So that resolved the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: @IvoHrádek yes, you're right I run migration before adding nullable(), but, it's working now.
Thank you.

Comment: @Naj good that you solved the problem. So don't forget to write an answer to your own question since you were able to solve it. So people that face the same problem can find a solution in your question :)

Comment: @Naj - You're welcome :). I've created "formal" answer for your question, as Artenes suggested, so if you are satisfied with my answer mark it as solution please or add your own answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `'domain_id' doesn't have a default value` suggest, that you have run

```
 $ php artisan migrate
```

before you have actually added `nullable()` constraint to foreign key. Note that default value for `nullable` columns is `NULL` for most databases.

In order to solve this, I suggest you either to re-create the tables, meaning, drop whole database with all tables and re-run `migrate` again. This is only in case you can afford to lose your data.

If not, you can create another migration, which alter the table by adding `nullable` constraint. Moreove you will probably have to update your data as well.